# How to capture and convert textbox into pdf file format?

Tags: c#

I want to capture my text box and convert it into the PDF format.
I tried the following code, but it captures the whole screen. How can I capture only my textbox values?

1. Code:

   ```
   try
   {
       Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
       using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
       {
           using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
           {
               g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty,
                                bounds.Size);
           }
           bitmap.Save("C://Rectangle.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
   }
   ```
2. for exporting pdf:

   ```
   captureScreen();
   var doc = new PdfDocument();
   var oPage = new PdfPage();
   doc.Pages.Add(oPage);
   oPage.Rotate = 90;
   XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage);
   XImage img = XImage.FromFile(@"C://Rectangle.bmp");
   xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
   doc.Save("C://RectangleDocument.pdf");
   doc.Close();
   ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please compare the question now with what you originally asked. See a difference? In the future, please make sure your questions are properly formatted from the beginning. Properly formatted questions are more likely to be answered.

Comment: I have error for references :PdfDocument ,PdfPage ,XGraphics ,XImage can you mention these references please?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `this.Bounds` but `yourTextBox.Bounds`.

Comment: thanx I used this, I have error for references :PdfDocument ,PdfPage ,XGraphics ,XImage can you mention these references please?

Comment: @user1734602: No, I can't because I don't know these classes. They are from the PDF library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact solution but some hint into the right direction.
The following code takes a screenshot of a given dialog with the specified rectangle. You can modify it to extract the textbox from the screenshot of the client area (dialog without titlebar,...)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WINDOWINFO
{
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    public RECT rcWindow;
    public RECT rcClient;
    public UInt32 dwStyle;
    public UInt32 dwExStyle;
    public UInt32 dwWindowStatus;
    public UInt32 cxWindowBorders;
    public UInt32 cyWindowBorders;
    public UInt16 atomWindowType;
    public UInt16 wCreatorVersion;
}
```

A bit of native magic via P/I:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref WINDOWINFO windowInfo);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, TernaryRasterOperations dwRop);
```

Dialog screenshot method. Get the hwnd with the Handle-property of any Windows Form.

```
protected Bitmap Capture(IntPtr hwnd, Rectangle rect)
{
    WINDOWINFO winInf = new WINDOWINFO();
    winInf.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(winInf);
    bool succ = PINativeOperator.GetWindowInfo(hwnd, ref winInf);

    if (!succ)
        return null;

    int width = winInf.rcClient.right - winInf.rcClient.left;
    int height = winInf.rcClient.bottom - winInf.rcClient.top;

    if (width == 0 || height == 0)
        return null;

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd);
    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();

    if(rect == Rectangle.Empty) {
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
    Graphics bmpG = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    PINativeOperator.BitBlt(bmpG.GetHdc(), 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, hdc, rect.X, rect.Y, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
    bmpG.ReleaseHdc();

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: thanx, I have error for references :PdfDocument ,PdfPage ,XGraphics ,XImage can you mention these references please?

Comment: I guess you are using itext# library. Have you downloaded the latest assemblies and referenced them from your project?